# Error in Visual Studio while trying to clone a git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio

Trying to clone a GIT (that's on TFS) repository, in Visual Studio 2013.

I've done this a bunch of times on different machines, though this one machine is giving me an error, as shown in the screenshot.

We have an extension installed that gives us the Microsoft Git Provider for the source control.

After connecting to the server and clicking 'clone Repository', then selecting `d:\our project folder' we get the message below:

Has anybody seen this before? Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

**Update**

Still no idea, though had to use Git command line to clone the repo. Any answer would be great. For some reason it seems VS is convinced we're trying to use TFS (you get more options in the team explorer) - no matter how many times we set the source control provider to MS Git Provider.